# Using react-router with express gets in the way of logout?

Tags: express, routes, react-router

**My Setup:**

I have react router to handle component changes and express to run get requests from my database.

React is on port 3000

express is on port 5000.

react is setup to proxy to port 5000 in a setupProxy.js file in it's client folder, and in it's package Json is a proxy instruction.

**setupProxy.js**

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(proxy('/auth', { target: 'http://localhost:5000/' }));
};
```

**react package.json (partial)**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000", // <--important detail here
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
```

In express i have passport setup to login and it works! Yay! I can send the jsons I need based on my initial axios request for user login.

**The problem**

This is my logout instructions in express:

```
app.get("/logout", function(req, res) {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect("/");
});
```

for logout I use a dead simple href="/logout" the default code for doing so in passport js. For logging in I do href="/auth/google" again pretty simple and that works. Logout does not logout and redirect to home and instead goes to /logout and stays there leaving me logged in and stuck.

I'm guessing this is happening because it's interfering with react router, as this keeps happening and im trying to rework my backend code to fix this. Of course I'm not really clear on the why or how of it yet. I would greatly appreciate any input on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

So the solution appears to be that I should be running a fetch request and not a direct link. I changed my href to an onclick handleLogout function as shown here:

```
const handleLogout = () => {
  axios.get("http://localhost:3000/logout").catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
};
```

Hope this helps future generations